# Can netty be used with jssc for serial comms?

Tags: serial-port, arm, netty, rxtx, jssc

I've used netty with udp and tcp protocols.

To my surprise it can be used with serial port as well.

Transport used is rxtx, there are a very few positive recommendations for rxtx.

Can netty be used with jssc instead of rxtx?

Should an application developer really care about the underlying implementation (rxtx or jssc)?

Should there be a problem developing in x86 then swapping to ARM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no support for jssc, but you could write your own transport implementation using it.

Answer (score -1):

As Norman said you could write your own jssc channel implementation to make it work with netty. However you may find ready libraries here below:

Original lib:
https://github.com/jkschneider/netty-jssc

My fork with some fixes:
https://github.com/tttomat19/netty-jssc

Regarding ARM/x86 question I believe jssc supports ARM, but I did not try it.

Regarding rxtx and jssc comparison I had unpleasant experience with rxtx performance and maven build.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14181032)

Comment: @JeffRSon this was no longer link only question, it was edited 4 days ago and it answers for most of questions asked.